# find biggest interval in list of time stamps ( Perl preferred )

Tags: python, regex, perl, parsing, scripting

I'd accept any of the interpreted languages Perl, Python, Bash, etc.. but I'd prefer Perl because it is what I am trying to learn.  I have a list of timestamps like:

```
17:31:16
17:31:16
17:31:18
17:31:29
```

I want to find all of the largest intervals (top 5) between any 2 consecutive lines, and return the time stamps and line numbers.  Basically this is a log file for a software build and I am trying to determine which steps took the longest.  The example I gave was actually already filtered, lines actually look like:
      [15:57:42]:   CC      net/sunrpc/xprtsock.o
If you can give me a program that parses that format it would be a little easier, and return the line number where the biggest differences in time occurred.

This is what I used to isolate the timestamps from the log

```
   perl -lane 'print $1 if $_ =~ /^\[(\d+:\d+:\d+)\]:*/'
```

The type of output I would like to achieve is something like:

```
 line 574 20:04:54
 line 575 20:24:55
 Difference 00:20:01
```

If you don't want to solve the problem, I would be happy to see some pseudocode or get any advice at all.  I have spent time and have no useful code to show for it.

Comment: Do any intervals cross midnight?  Do any intervals overlap with daylight savings adjustments?

Comment: @pilcrow No, there are no issues like that for this specific data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd upgrade your time-matching regex a bit, to capture the components of the time separately.  Do we have to worry about builds started before midnight and running until the early morning of the next day?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $oldtime = "";  # hh:mm:ss for end of long interval
my $oldlineno = 0; # line number in the file of second line
my $oldoffset = 0; # offset in seconds from midnight of second command
my $olddiff = 0;   # time taken for longest command

sub hhmmss
{
    my($time) = @_;
    my(@tm) = (int($time/3600), int($time/60)%60, $time%60);
    return @tm;
}

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    next unless m/^((\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d))\s+/;
    my $newoffset = (($2 * 60) + $3) * 60 + $4;
    if ($oldoffset == 0)
    {
        $oldtime = $1;
        $olddiff = 0;
        $oldoffset = $newoffset;
        $oldlineno = $.;
    }
    elsif (($newoffset - $oldoffset) > $olddiff)
    {
        $oldtime = $1;
        $olddiff = $newoffset - $oldoffset;
        $oldoffset = $newoffset;
        $oldlineno = $.;
    }
}

if ($oldoffset != 0)
{
    my $prvlineno = $oldlineno - 1;
    my $newoffset = $oldoffset - $olddiff;
    my(@tm) = hhmmss($newoffset);
    printf "line $prvlineno: %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n", $tm[0], $tm[1], $tm[2];
    print  "line $oldlineno: $oldtime\n";
    @tm = hhmmss($olddiff);
    printf "diff:   %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n", $tm[0], $tm[1], $tm[2];
}
```

Given data file (`data`) and the script above (`dt.pl`):

```
17:31:16 line1
17:31:18 line2
17:31:29 line3
17:33:59 line4
18:00:21 line5
18:21:03 line6
18:41:25 line7
19:51:54 line8
19:52:34 line9
```

The scriptlet below produces the output shown:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 9); do sed ${i}q data | perl dt.pl; done | so
line 0: 17:31:16
line 1: 17:31:16
diff:   00:00:00
line 1: 17:31:16
line 2: 17:31:18
diff:   00:00:02
line 2: 17:31:18
line 3: 17:31:29
diff:   00:00:11
line 3: 17:31:29
line 4: 17:33:59
diff:   00:02:30
line 4: 17:33:59
line 5: 18:00:21
diff:   00:26:22
line 4: 17:33:59
line 5: 18:00:21
diff:   00:26:22
line 6: 18:00:21
line 7: 18:41:25
diff:   00:41:04
line 7: 18:41:25
line 8: 19:51:54
diff:   01:10:29
line 7: 18:41:25
line 8: 19:51:54
diff:   01:10:29
$
```

> I'd love to hear how you thought about the problem before you wrote any of the code.

This was clearly a problem where it was necessary to keep a record of the (relevant parts of the) previous line information to calculate the difference between it and the current line.  You also need to keep the current maximum difference, which can't formally be established until you've read a second matching line.  This drives the design. The big repeat in the code which could be reduced to nothing by assigning 3 values unconditionally and the fourth (`$olddiff`) conditionally.  After that, it is mostly a question of mechanics and tactics.

Matching across multiple lines like this is a nuisancy process; you have to deal with preserving appropriate state.  Partly, it is a question of experience; after you've done this kind of thing a few dozen times, it doesn't take as long the next time.

Comment: That is a great job, thank you!  I'd love to hear how you thought about the problem before you wrote any of the code.  I think my inability to approach this like a programmer was a big obstacle for me.  What was the thought process?

Answer (score 1):

Just get the biggest difference

```
perl -l -n -e 'BEGIN {$m=0;$last=0;$am=$.;} /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/; $v=($1*3600)+($2*60)+$3;   if ($last && $v-$last > $m) { $am=$.; $m=$v-$last;} $last=$v; END { print "max diff ",$m, " at line $am\n" }' d.txt
```

Top 5

```
perl -l -n -e 'BEGIN {%h=();$last=0;} /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/; $v=($1*3600)+($2*60)+$3;   if ($last) { $h{$v-$last}=$.;} $last=$v; END { for ((sort {$b <=> $a} keys %h)[0..4]) { print "line ",$h{$_}," $_"; }}' d.txt
```

In python

```
last = 0
list = []
linenumber = 1
for t in (open("d.txt","r").readlines()):
    q=3600
    v=0
    for x in t.split(":"):
        v = v + q*int(x)
        q = q / 60
    if (last >0):
      list.append([v-last, linenumber])
    last = v
    linenumber = linenumber + 1

top = sorted(list, key=lambda n: n[0], reverse=True)[0:5]
print top
```

Comment: Very impressive, and very helpful.  Thank you.  I am going to study this for a while.

Comment: Would you mind breaking down your approach and thought process for me a bit?